# Free app asks purchase options dialog in Google play store open beta testing

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I have released my app on Google play store open beta testing channel 2 days before.It is visible to users,but some devices shows purchase options dialog even it is free app.Uninstall old app cache also not works.

Comment: If it's free and it shows a purchase dialog, how much is it asking the users to pay for? If it's 0.00 then there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It shows blank white dialog with only title as purchase options.

Comment: Oh, so it's not asking users for money then? Follow what Nick said. You can also try to open a report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a bug. If you can reproduce it on a device, then can you take a screenshot (and ideally a bug report too) and contact Play developer support through the Play Console help section.

Comment: Yes I have contacted Play developer support,the asks for screeenshots and other device details. I have sent it.Once I get response from support,I will update solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the same behavior today when trying to install on S7 Edge an app that installs another app.  For example, an app that says "Uses ARCore - this will be installed as part of the installation process" (A good example is Figment AR).

This might not be the answer, but I hope it helps.  If I installed the ARCore prior to the main installation then the main install worked just fine.  Note that I did try and few AR apps before figuring this out.

Comment: Yes It is a default behaviour when using ARCore. If ARCore app not installed,it will display a dialog to install ARCore app.This is good. But instead of this, I am getting Purchase Options dialog.It should be a bug.